# Understanding what AJAX is capable of and its limitations

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml

I have heard about AJAX for years but I never felt the need or the intrest on learning it, I knew it was a mix of Javascript and XML but I never took the time to actully try to understand it, until now.

This is what I currently understand about AJAX. Ajax is not a language, it is just a combination of existing technologies, basically JavaScript and XML (and possibly HTML and CSS) and uses the XMLHttpRequest to comunicate with the server in the background to update/load only parts of a page instead of reloading the whole page.

Things I don't fully understand.

1- Is there any AJAX documentation or API that I can refer to to see what functions/options AJAX offers?

2- Why every book in Amazon seem to be old? Is this because AJAX this is not a language and doesn't change?

3- I read the tutorial at [www.w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/Ajax/default.asp) and I was wondering if what is shown in this tutorial is basically all AJAX can do, basically, Request and respoind to a server?

Again, all I'm trying to understand here is basically how much of a learning I still need to go through in order to have a better understanding about AJAX.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long story short: AJAX lets you make calls to the server without submitting a form or navigating the page. That is **all** it does.

Originally it stood for "Asynchronous Javascript And XML" because the XMLHttpRequest object was designed to receive updates in XML format. Microsoft added the object so that the Outlook Web interface could pop up new mail alerts by polling the server.

Since then, most programmers have eschewed the use of XML as the data exchange protocol and rely on [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) instead. JSON is far easier to parse and work with.

While I could go through some examples of the low level XMLHttpRequest interactions, [other sources](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29#Example) have that well covered.

Instead, I'm going to give you a bit of advice. [Study Javascript](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v2ifWcnQs6M&noredirect=1) and consider learning the [jQuery API](https://jquery.org/). JQuery forces functional programming and makes common activities like AJAX calls super-simple to accomplish. You'll learn to be a better Javascript programmer because of it and will hopefully learn to make your sites more interactive thanks to the power that background server requests bring to the table.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I indeed know a little bit of Javascript and jQuery I just never took the time to research about AJAX. Makes sense now.

Answer (score 1):

Although the 'X' in AJAX stands for XML,  applications today are more likely to use JSON encoding over XML as the return data can be evaluated directly by the browsers JavaScript interpreter.  The core enabling JavaScript object is XMLHttpRequest which was originally developed as an ActiveX component for IE 5.  It has since become a standard object in all web browser implementations.  You can read about the core functionality here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest.

Your best bet would be to research modern JavaScript frameworks such as jQuery.  http://www.jquery.com/ for information on how to use AJAX technology within your web applications.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a vague question, and likely to get some down votes, but I think it's specific enough that it does warrant some information.

In a nutshell, AJAX is a why for JavaScript to request information asynchronously. The XML portion is a bit of a misnomer, since you don't have to explicitly deal with XML at all. Frequently, you'll use AJAX requests to read in JSON information (since it's so easy to parse and use).

AJAX isn't really a language, or even a framework. It's a technique. It is made possible by the XMLHttpRequest class, along with some related technologies. Since it isn't 100% consistent across all browsers, it is usually best to use a third-party library. jQuery and most other larger frameworks usually have it built in. You can also find some small AJAX-only libraries, like this [XMLHttpRequest project on Github](https://github.com/ilinsky/xmlhttprequest).

Every book on the technique is probably old because nothing has really changed substantially since the technique starting becoming popular. I've been using it for at least the past 3-5 years, and not much has changed (other than a bit more standardization in modern browsers).

The respond and request is basically all AJAX can do. However, that enables a whole world of possibilities. Long story short, it's a way to communicate with the server without having to refresh the page, allowing for much smoother UI and UX.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to think about it is that it lets you fetch data without a page reload.

Think about how Google Maps loads in bits of the map as you drag around - it clearly doesn't load the map for the whole world.

In older map sites you clicked a left, right, up or down arrow, the page reloaded and the new data was shown.

AJAX lets you make pages feel much faster and smoother.

Technically JSON is usually used instead of XML as it's more Javascripty than XML.

Most sites likely use it somewhere or other, ranging from loading sidebar widgets after the main content, to the whole app, like Gmail.